# Why is path_provider in dart awaited?

Tags: dart

Why are directory methods in path_provider awaited like so? They are not over the internet calls to the network.

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path;

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
```

Edit:
I don't think I was specific enough. I understand from the method signature that it returns a future. I was more asking as to why it is a future, why the methods are asynchronous.

Is it because they are kind of like unix file system writes/reads, ie blocking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the underlying code is asynchronous, and returns a `Future`. To get the value returned from a `Future` you must either use `await` or `.then()`.

`path_provider` uses [`MethodChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html) to call native code, and the `MethodChannel.invokeMethod()` function is asynchronous. Specifically, the interface to native code ([platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)) works by sending a message and waiting for a response. It does this asynchronously so it does not lock up your app while waiting for your request to complete on the native side.

> Flutter’s platform-specific API support does not rely on code generation, but rather on a flexible message passing style:
>
> - The Flutter portion of the app sends messages to its host, the iOS or Android portion of the app, over a platform channel.
> - The host listens on the platform channel, and receives the message. It then calls into any number of platform-specific APIs—using the native programming language—and sends a response back to the client, the Flutter portion of the app.

Futures and asynchronous code are not just for network/internet related work.

Answer (score 2):

`path_provider`'s API is asynchronous because it communicates with platform-native Android or iOS code, and [Flutter traditionally uses an asynchronous message-passing system for that communication](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

Conceivably now that `dart:ffi` is mature, `path_provider` someday could provide an FFI-based interface that is synchronous instead.  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112009.